# VBA running a function by name of string

Tags: excel, vba, string, function, compiler-errors

Is it possible to run a function bases on a variable from a cell in excel?

```
Option Explicit

Dim retval As Integer

Sub main()
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim usedFun As String
    'get function name from cell
    usedFun = Range("C3").Value
    
    Dim firNum As Integer
    Dim secNum As Integer
    firNum = 3
    secNum = 1
 
    'run named function
    Run usedFun(firNum, secNum)
    
    Debug.Print retval
    
End Sub

Public Function plus(firNum As Integer, secNum As Integer)
    retval = firNum + secNum
End Function

Public Function minus(firNum As Integer, secNum As Integer)
    retval = firNum - secNum
End Function
```

I get "compile error, expected array"
can do it with case select, but many cases end up in clumsy-looking code
any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close - it would be:

```
Run usedFun, firNum, secNum
```

Comment: thank you @Rory , that works great !
  I actually tried that too except for the comma after usedFun